# Migrating from basemap Near Sided Perspective (nsper) projection to using cartopy Geostationary projection

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I'm trying to migrate some code away from basemap to cartopy, and I'm quite perplexed as why I can't get this to work. However, I basically want to have a scatter plot on something similar 'nsper' projection provided by basemap.

The original code looks like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as  plt
lon_0 = -75.0
image_name = 'original.png'
lon_swath1 = np.arange(-65,66,1)
lat_swath1 = np.zeros(np.shape(lon_swath1))

lat_swath2 = np.arange(-40,40,1)
lon_swath2 = -75.0*np.ones(np.shape(lat_swath2))

m = Basemap(projection='nsper',lon_0=lon_0,lat_0=0)

x1,y1 = m(lon_swath1,lat_swath1)
x2,y2 = m(lon_swath2,lat_swath2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6.5))
m.drawcoastlines()
m.scatter(x1, y1, s=2.5, marker="o")
m.scatter(x2, y2, s=2.5, marker="x")
fig.savefig('%s' % image_name, format='png')
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

And produces a figure that looks like this:
[original basemap figure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYUet.png)

If I try to do what I think is the equivalent in cartopy, I don't get the full globe, and I can't no matter how hard I try

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as  plt
lon_0 = -75.0
image_name = 'test.png'
lon_swath1 = np.arange(-65,66,1)
lat_swath1 = np.zeros(np.shape(lon_swath1))

lat_swath2 = np.arange(-40,40,1)
lon_swath2 = -75.0*np.ones(np.shape(lat_swath2))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6.5))
ax = plt.axes(projection= ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=lon_0))
ax.coastlines()
plt.scatter(lon_swath1, lat_swath1, s=2.5, marker="o", transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.scatter(lon_swath2, lat_swath2, s=2.5, marker="x", transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
fig.savefig('%s' % image_name, format='png')
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

[zoomed in Geostationary equivalent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s43tC.png)

What I want is a full globe extent, however, if I try to force the issue with the following, I get an error.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as  plt
lon_0 = -75.0
image_name = 'broken.png'
lon_swath1 = np.arange(-65,66,1)
lat_swath1 = np.zeros(np.shape(lon_swath1))

lat_swath2 = np.arange(-40,40,1)
lon_swath2 = -75.0*np.ones(np.shape(lat_swath2))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6.5))
ax = plt.axes(projection= ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=lon_0))
extent = ax.get_extent()
ax.coastlines()
plt.scatter(lon_swath1, lat_swath1, s=2.5, marker="o", transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.scatter(lon_swath2, lat_swath2, s=2.5, marker="x", transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.set_extent(extent,crs=ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=lon_0))
fig.savefig('%s' % image_name, format='png')
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

The error I get:

```
    ax.set_extent(extent,crs=ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=lon_0))
      File "/users/karpowicz/.local/external/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 652, in set_extent
        ylim=self.projection.y_limits))
ValueError: Failed to determine the required bounds in projection coordinates. Check that the values provided are within the valid range (x_limits=[-5372584.78444, 5372584.78444], y_limits=[-5372584.78444, 5372584.78444]).
```

If anyone has any suggestions, or ideas I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. @ResMar's assertion that the extents aren't in a projection is incorrect. According to [the documentation for `get_extent()`](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/geoaxes.html?highlight=geoaxes#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.get_extent):

> If no crs is given, the returned extents' coordinate system will be
>       the CRS of this Axes.

Even if the extents returned by that function are outside the x and y limits specified in the error message, it's possible to provide extents which are within those limits but still produce the error.

Edit: @ResMar is correct in saying that `ax.set_global()` is the right way to go in this case

Comment: The API for this feature is non-obvious to me, and the docs aren't very helpful. But I see you work at the Met office, so methink you know better than I.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your map is in a projection but the extent you're trying to pass is not. I've honestly forgotten what the specific fix for this is (I've run into it quite a bit before), but here's a shortcut—throw out the `ax.set_extent` and use this instead:

```
ax.set_global()
```